# Git diff with a sub-directory in the remote

Tags: git, git-diff

The git repository I have in my local (say, `a`) is a subdirectory of another git repository (say, `b`). My goal is to check diff between my files and the files in the matched subdirectory of remote `b`. I know the path of the subdirectory (say, `subdir/`). How can I get the desired diff?

I tried,
`git diff master <a remote commit> -- subdir/`
But it still treats `sample.txt` in my local and `subdir/sample.txt` in remote `b` as different. What can I do to achieve the desired diff? Also, what if I don't know the subdirectory location as well?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out,

`git diff master <a remote commit>:subdir`